# Can I license photos of physical products / equipment I took as Creative Commons?

Tags: creative-commons

I want to document a scientific experiments I've presenced on a blog post.

To do that, I want to give clear descriptions of each commercial equipment used, and using photos would be a great addition.

Can I just take a photo of the equipment myself and use it on my blogpost with a Creative Commons license?

As a concrete example, the equipment I have in mind this time is the [Oxford Nanpore Technologies MinION](https://nanoporetech.com/products/minion) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20190825022606/https://nanoporetech.com/products/minion)).

The design of that equipment closed source and has related patents, but I just want a picture showing how the user will see while using it, nothing that would allow reverse engineering undocumented aspects of it.

As you would expect, the object design itself does not have a particularly artistic design and is purely utilitarian.

The equipment does have a logo or sticker with the name of the company, but I believe that this falls under trademark and is likely not "creative enough" be copyrighted, but how do I check that? Alternatively, I could edit the photo to blur the logo is that's an issue.

All of this supposing of course that I don't have any explicit NDA or contractual restriction with the seller.

I've seen plenty of car pictures marked as creative commons, so my intuition is that this should be fine, while what is mostly not fine are copyrighted materials such as films and pictures taken by others.

Comment: What jurisdiction are you in?

Comment: @MadHatter UK. But would be good to know for US as well at least.

Comment: See also [Can a self-made photo of a mass product (not containing any logos) be claimed as entirely own work?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/16720/can-a-self-made-photo-of-a-mass-product-not-containing-any-logos-be-claimed-as)

Comment: In general, when you take a photo, the copyright to that photo belongs to you. Of course, it is possible that taking a photo could break some other law (e.g. voyeurism, exposing trade secrets, taking photos of military), but those situations are more of a legal question.

Comment: @Brandin thanks for the link, that does come very close to what I'm asking.

Comment: The question comes down to: Can I copy-right my photos?